# -Xmx attribute and available system memory correlation

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a question on my mind. Let's assume that I have two parameters passed to JVM:
-Xms256mb -Xmx1024mb
At the beginning of the program 256MB is allocated. Next, some objects are created and JVM process tries to allocate more memory. Let's say that JVM needs to allocate 800MB. Xmx attribute allows that but the memory which is currently available on the system (let's say Linux/Windows) is 600MB. Is it possible that OutOfMemoryError will be thrown? Or maybe swap mechanism will play a role?

My second question is related to the quality of GC algorithms. Let's say that I have jdk1.5u7 and jdk1.5u22. Is it possible that in the latter JVM the memory leaks vanish and OutOfMemoryError does not occur? Can the quality of GC be better in the latest version?

Comment: Regardless of if the GC is better in later versions, if you're pushing it so close to the point of an out of memory error, you can't rely on the GC to clean it up reliably... you need more memory allocated.

Comment: I have noticed that jdk1.5u7 (Linux) crashes with OutOfMemoryError while jdk1.5u17 (Windows) survives. The same code and attributes are used.

Comment: Did you linux machine have a swap?

Answer (score 2):

The quality of the GC (barring a buggy GC) does not affect memory leaks, as memory leaks are an artifact of the application -- GC can't collect what isn't actual garbage.

If a JVM needs more memory, it will take it from the system. If the system can swap, it will swap (like any other process). If the system can not swap, your JVM will fail with a system error, not an OOM exception, because the system can not satisfy the request and and this point its effectively fatal.

As a rule, you NEVER want to have an active JVM partially swapped out. GC event will crush you as the system thrashes cycling pages through the virtual memory system. It's one thing to have a idle background JVM swapped out as a whole, but if you machine as 1G of RAM and your main process wants 1.5GB, then you have a major problem.

The JVM like room to breathe. I've seen JVMs in a GC death spiral when they didn't have enough memory, even though they didn't have memory leaks. They simply didn't have enough working set. Adding another chunk of heap transformed that JVM from awful to happy sawtooth GC graphs.

Give a JVM the memory it needs, you and it will be much happier.

Answer (score 2):

"Memory" and "RAM" aren't the same thing.  Memory includes virtual memory (swap), so you can allocate a total of free RAM+ free swap before you get the OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 0):

Allocation depends on the used OS.
If you allocate too much memory, maybe you could end up having loaded portions into swap, which is slow.
If the your program runs fater os slower depends on how VM handle the memory.

I would not specify a heap that's not so big to make sure it don't occupy all the memory preventing the slows from VM.

Answer (score -1):

Concerning your first question:
Actually if the machine can not allocate the `1024` MB that you asked as max heap size it will not even start the JVM.
I know this because I noticed it often trying to open eclipse with large heap size and the OS could not allocate the larger heap space the JVM failed to load. You could also try it out yourself to confirm. So the rest of the details are irrelevant to you. If course if your program uses too much swap (same as in all languages) then the performance will be horrible.

Concerning your second question:

> the memory leaks vanish

Not possible as they are bugs *you* will have to fix

> and OutOfMemoryError does not occur? Can the quality of GC be better
>   in the latest version?

This could happen, if for example some different algorithm in GC is used and it manages to kick-in before you seeing the exception. But if you have a memory leak then it would probable mask it or you would see it intermittent.
Also various JVMs have different GCs you can configure

**Update:**
I have to admit (after see @Orochi note) that I noticed the behavior on max heap on Windows. I can not say for sure that this applies to linux as well. But you could try it yourself.

**Update 2:**
As an answer to comments of @DennisCheung
From [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html)(my emphasis):

> > The table shows both the maximum Java heap possible and a **recommended** limit for the maximum Java heap size setting ......It is important to have more physical memory than is required by all of the processes on the machine combined to prevent paging or swapping. Paging reduces the performance of the system and affects the performance of the Java memory management system.

Comment: JVM will verify your argument before it start the VM,  there are few  limit on the Xmx by OS and VM version. But it is not related to current memory allocation status.

Comment: @DennisCheung:Not sure what your mean by limit. In Windows in 4GB RAM I have noticed that if the requested max heap can not allocated the JVM is not started

Comment: There is a hardcore limit of Xmx by Sun/Oracle JVM. For windows it should be 1000M, 1024M or 2048MB depending on the version.  Check their document for detail.   I don't have the link on hand as they keep changing their website.

Comment: @DennisCheung:I don't believe there is one.Their is a recomendation e.g. IBM recommends for its JVM on 32 bit systems to not exceed 1.5GB but that recommendation is only because the higher the java heap size set, the less native memory you have and as a result you could still end up with OOM during thread creation, permgen etc. But as far as I know there is no other limitation on the actual number set. If you have a reference I would be happy to know it.

Comment: @DennisCheung:And also what you say does not make my answer wrong since the end result is the same.An inappropriate value for max heap size can not be set.

Comment: believe it or not, it exists. I am searching the link but while all sun.com links broke or missing...